# No incoming connection with Visual Studio and XAMPP

Tags: c#, sockets, xampp

I have written a C# application which includes a connection listener.

This listener is set to wait for connections on port 21.

I also have a client written in flash, which is embedded in an html page on my local XAMPP site, and which should connect to the listener (on port 21).

Now, when I open my application, the client and the listener start without any problem, but then the listener does not receive any accept request (or message).

I've also tried to disable Microsoft Security Essentials and the Windows Firewall, but nothing changed.

I'm running a 64bit version of Windows7 Home Premium.

Comment: How does your client call the server ?  Is the address hard-coded ?
Can you post us some code?

Comment: The ip the clients needs to connect to can be modified in the html page itself. I'm currently using "127.0.0.1" on both the application, and the client